# Store to DB opencv data

Tags: opencv

I had got keypoints and descriptors of image. Now I want store it in DB. Is in opencv any way to do that(like save in file) or any idea how to do that?

P.S. C++.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [file input and output XML and YAML files](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html).

Comment: thanks, but I don't want use file, I need serialize it and write to db without "intermediate file".

Comment: I don't think this is something that opencv supports. However, I'm sure you can find something within the C++ itself.